# find nearby string if a word match in a string using regex php

Tags: php, regex, string

I am trying to find nearby string if a word match in a string using regex php.
I will explain you clearly with an example

```
$string = "this is  my sample text A.B.C. ABC Organization
bla la lbls bla 
Telefon:0112 116 19 94 this is my sample text";
```

//this is my string
here, I will search with a keyword.
For example with phone number `0112 116 19 94`
i need a regular expression which gets 30 characters before the phone number and after the phone number. what should i do for that

Plz help me in writing the regex for that .
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i need a regular expression which gets 30 characters before the phone number and after the phone number

You can try:

```
$regex = '/.{1,30}' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '.{1,30}/s';
```

Where `$search` is your search keyword.

Comment: I think you mean to use `.` instead of `+`.